# Filtering a pyspark dataframe to get rows from last N days doesn't work correctly and returns some data before the stated date

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, datetime

I added a new column to my spark dataframe by combining these 4 columns  `year,month,day,time_hour` as follow:

```
df = df.withColumn("tmp_timestamp", concat_ws(" ", concat_ws("_", col("year"), col("month"), col("day")), col("time_hour")))\
       .withColumn("tsmp", unix_timestamp("tmp_timestamp", "yyyy_MM_dd HH"))\
       .withColumn("date_time_EET", from_utc_timestamp(col("tsmp").cast('timestamp'), "EET"))\
       .drop("tmp_timestamp")
```

And here is the result:

```
+-------+--------+------+---------+-------------+----------+---------------------+
|year   |month   |day   |time_hour|tmp_timestamp|tsmp      |date_time_EET        |
+-------+--------+------+---------+-------------+----------+---------------------+
|2021   |1       |22    |0        |2021_1_22 0  |1611273600|2021-01-22 02:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |22    |9        |2021_1_22 9  |1611306000|2021-01-22 11:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |22    |4        |2021_1_22 4  |1611288000|2021-01-22 06:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |22    |8        |2021_1_22 8  |1611302400|2021-01-22 10:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |22    |23       |2021_1_22 23 |1611356400|2021-01-23 01:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |22    |7        |2021_1_22 7  |1611298800|2021-01-22 09:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |22    |10       |2021_1_22 10 |1611309600|2021-01-22 12:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |22    |4        |2021_1_22 4  |1611288000|2021-01-22 06:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |22    |8        |2021_1_22 8  |1611302400|2021-01-22 10:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |22    |23       |2021_1_22 23 |1611356400|2021-01-23 01:00:00.0|
+-------+--------+------+---------+-------------+----------+---------------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

Now, I need to filter over this new dataframe and get the rows their `date_time_EET` value is higher than a specific date, e.g. getting the data for the last 10 days. This is how I'm doing it:

```
N = 10
date_N_days_ago = start_day - timedelta(days=N)  # In this example date_N_days_ago will be 2021-01-24

df.filter(col('date_time_EET')> date_N_days_ago)\
    .select("year","month","day","time_hour","date_time_EET", )\
    .dropDuplicates(["ts_year","ts_month","ts_day","time_hour"])\
    .orderBy("ts_year","ts_month","ts_day","time_hour",)\
    .show(100, False)
```

which gives me the following result:

```
+-------+--------+------+---------+---------------------+
|year   |month   |day   |time_hour|date_time_EET        |
+-------+--------+------+---------+---------------------+
|2021   |1       |23    |21       |2021-01-23 23:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |23    |22       |2021-01-24 00:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |23    |23       |2021-01-24 01:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |24    |0        |2021-01-24 02:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |24    |1        |2021-01-24 03:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |24    |2        |2021-01-24 04:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |24    |3        |2021-01-24 05:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |24    |4        |2021-01-24 06:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |24    |5        |2021-01-24 07:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |24    |6        |2021-01-24 08:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |24    |7        |2021-01-24 09:00:00.0|
|2021   |1       |24    |8        |2021-01-24 10:00:00.0|
...
```

Why do I get the first row where date_time_EET is "2021-01-23 23:00:00.0", while `date_N_days_ago` is `2021-01-24`? Also, when I add another condition to the `filter` to returns dates before the `start_date` it doesn't return the data for the last hour (`2021-02-02 23:00:00.0` is missing):

```
df.filter((col('date_time_EET')> date_N_days_ago) & (col('date_time_EET') <= start_date))\
    .select("year","month","day","time_hour","date_time_EET", )\
    .dropDuplicates(["ts_year","ts_month","ts_day","time_hour"])\
    .orderBy("ts_year","ts_month","ts_day","time_hour",)\
    .show(100, False)

+-------+--------+------+---------+---------------------+
|year   |month   |day   |time_hour|date_time_EET        |
+-------+--------+------+---------+---------------------+
....
|2021   |2       |2     |16       |2021-02-02 18:00:00.0|
|2021   |2       |2     |17       |2021-02-02 19:00:00.0|
|2021   |2       |2     |18       |2021-02-02 20:00:00.0|
|2021   |2       |2     |19       |2021-02-02 21:00:00.0|
|2021   |2       |2     |20       |2021-02-02 22:00:00.0|
+-------+--------+------+---------+---------------------+
```

Comment: It looks like it's related to timezones... For last 10 days, you can use:  `filter(col('date_time_EET') > date_add(current_timestamp(), -10) )`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to convert the time to EET timezone before doing the comparison:

```
import pytz

date_N_days_ago = (start_day - timedelta(days=N)).astimezone(pytz.timezone('EET'))
```